# Generalization of some infinite series containing binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, pi

On a page [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Binomial/23/02/). There are some infinite series in the form $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k^n}{\binom{2k}{k}}=\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c \pi}{d}$$
Where $n \in {[0,1,2,3,4...]}$ and for some natural numbers $a,b,c,d$.
the question is that- Is there any formula to find out $a , b , c , d$ with respect to every $n$?

Comment: There seems to be a $\sqrt{3}$ missing in the denominator of the latter fraction.

Comment: I think that a 3 should be included in the denominator of the first fraction. I also think that, including the remark by Peter Kosinar, "d" should be something like 3^(j+1/2).

Comment: The result is an hypergeometric FPQ function, ... which does not help a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe these come from
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{t^k}{{2k}\choose k} = \dfrac{t}{4-t} + 4 \dfrac{\sqrt{t}}{(4-t)^{3/2}} \arcsin(\sqrt{t}/2)$$
If this function is $F(t)$, then 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{k^n}{{2k} \choose k} = 
\left. \left(t \dfrac{d}{dt}\right)^n F(t)\right|_{t=1}$$
For example, for $n=13$ I get (with Maple's help)
$$  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{k^{13}}{{2k} \choose k} = {\frac {727348814}{3}}+{\frac {1315508114654}{59049}}\,\sqrt {3}\pi $$